# Rails and Jquery datepicker working with datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I would like the date picker update the "date" part of the datetime 
and time_select update the "time" part of a date time 
What I tried:

```
<%= f.text_field :Start_Time , :class => 'datepicker' %> <P>
<%= f.time_select :Start_Time, :class => 'time_select' ,:ignore_date => true %>
```

but it does not work

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5gQBBtVp8F1363IWsxzl9sF9QC9oAjP37r1e9pyS1NQ=",
 "booking"=>{"Create_Date"=>"",
 "Start_Time"=>"2013/03/06",
 "Start_Time(4i)"=>"18",
 "Start_Time(5i)"=>"06",
 .....
```

The datepicker could update a date field but cannot update the date part of datetime field
Could anyone tell me what is missing there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. You have to submit them as separate attributes and then write a method to join them in the model.

Alternatively, if you're using the jquery-ui datepicker, you can just add the [time addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) and  create a new css class 'datetime_picker' + js initializer. That way, you can do:

```
f.text_field :Start_Time , :class => 'datetime_picker'
```